# get info from nmcli linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, security, command, wifi

I am making a script in shell and I want to extract information from the command `nmcli`.

If I execute `nmcli -p dev wifi list` in a linux terminal I get a table with all Wi-Fi available. From each Wi-Fi (SSID) in the table I want to get **only** the SECURITY field.

So the output of the script would be something like:

```
SSID1 : SSID1-SECURITY

SSID2 : SSID2-SECURITY

...   :  ...
```

I've been searching for a while but haven't found how to do it :(

Can someone tell me how to get the security field from each SSID?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know much about `nmcli`, but I think you can do :

```
nmcli -p dev wifi list | grep 'SSID.*SECURITY'
```

Comment: I have already found the solution for this ! I just did nmcli -p -f SSID,SECURITY dev wifi list  and it worked :P